Aggregating Individual Events by Group ID at High Load in Near Real-Time via Flink
Pardon me if this is trivial however I don't have much experience with Flink outside of the docs.
Suppose there is a stream of purchases. Each purchase is separated by 1 second (or an arbitrary amount), and is related by the orderID.
Example list of events:
[
    {
        "item": "bananas",
        "cost": "9.99",
        "orderId": 12345,
        "timestamp": "2024-11-06T12:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "item": "apples",
        "cost": "5.49",
        "orderId": 12345,
        "timestamp": "2024-11-06T12:00:01Z"
    },
    {
        "item": "oranges",
        "cost": "7.29",
        "orderId": 12345,
        "timestamp": "2024-11-06T12:00:02Z"
    },
    {
        "item": "grapes",
        "cost": "12.99",
        "orderId": 12345,
        "timestamp": "2024-11-06T12:00:03Z"
    }
]

When one event arrives, I'd like to start an aggregation job and waits for subsequent events of the same orderId up to a certain time limit. The result will be:
{
    "total": "35.76",
    "items": ["bananas", "apples", "oranges", "grapes"]
}

So for instance, bananas arrive which triggers a job to wait for any other items that might match the same order ID. As each new item is aggregated, the timeout extends. Once the timeout hits 0, the aggregated event is sent off.

Bananas arrive, wait for 1 second...
Apples arrive 0.5 seconds later and is reduced to an aggregation. Wait time is reset to 1 second.
... etc.

Is this something that can trivially be done at high load? The idea of not wanting to use a window is that ideally, I'd like the wait time to be minimal so that the aggregation is sent as soon as possible.

The grouping semantics you've described is precisely what session windows do.
This can be done with a query like this in Flink SQL:
SELECT orderId, SUM(cost) AS total, ARRAY_AGG(item) AS items
  FROM TABLE(
    SESSION(DATA => TABLE orders, 
            TIMECOL => DESCRIPTOR(`timestamp`),
            GAP => INTERVAL '1' SECOND))
  GROUP BY orderId, window_start, window_end;


As @kkrugler noted in his answer, this requires that watermarks be defined on the timestamp column.

As David noted, a session window is what you want. Below is some Java code to do something similar to the SQL code above. A few additional comments...

You'll want to be assigning appropriate timestamps and watermarks based on your stream of events.
Latency will be impacted by your watermarking strategy. E.g. if you have a bounded out-of-orderness of 10 seconds, then that will delay generation of results by roughly 10 seconds.
The window end time will be the time of the last event that's part of a session, plus the 1 second maximum gap, minus 1 millisecond.
I've seen sessions window can create some performance issues at high loads. This is due to every event creating a window, which is then potentially merged multiple times with existing windows. But implementing your own sessionizing support via a KeyedProcessFunction is non-trivial.

The Java code looks something like:
   DataStream<Purchase> purchases = ...; // assumes timestamped records w/watermarks.

   purchases
      .keyBy(r -> r. orderId())
      .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
      .aggregate(new MyAggregateFunction());

   private static class MyAggregateFunction implements AggregateFunction<Purchase, CostAndItems, CostAndItems> {
      ... code to implement simple sum of cost and set of unique items
   }

